# How to save jpg image to database and then load it in Delphi using FIBplus and TImage?

Tags: delphi, timage, fibplus

How do I save a jpg image to database and then load it in Delphi using FIBplus and TImage?

Answer (score 4):

```
var
  S : TMemoryStream;
begin
  S := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TBlobField(AdoQuery1.FieldByName('ImageField')).SaveToStream(S);
    S.Position := 0;
    Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(S);
  finally
    S.Free;
  end;
end;
```

if you are using JPEG images, add JPG unit to **uses** clause of your unit file.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/articles/2161.php) explains it. Use SaveToStream and a TMemoryStream instead of SaveToFile if you don't want temporary files. TImage.Picture has a LoadFromStream which loads the image from the stream into the TImage for display.

Answer (score -1):

[Take a look here.](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa030601a.htm)
I think you have to convert it to a stream, store it and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Delphi 7 paradox table

insert dbimage to jpeg

```
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  BlobStream: TStream;
begin
  if openpicturedialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Sicil_frm.DBNavigator1.BtnClick(nbEdit);
    image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.FileName);
    try
       BlobStream := dm.sicil.CreateBlobStream(dm.sicil.FieldByName('Resim'),bmWrite);
       FileStream := TFileStream.Create(openpicturedialog1.FileName,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
       BlobStream.CopyFrom(FileStream,FileStream.Size);
       FileStream.Free;
       BlobStream.Free;
       Sicil_frm.DBNavigator1.BtnClick(nbPost);
       DM.SicilAfterScroll(dm.sicil);
     except
       dm.sicil.Cancel;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Error "Bitmap image is nat valid"